# Sqlalchemy datetime insert into Oracle

Tags: pandas, oracle, date, sqlalchemy

I'm using sqlalchemy and to_sql to insert my dateframe into my Oracle table.   Everything works, but I added a DATE column to the end of the table, and cannot get sqlalchemy to insert that value.

Here is the short code snippet:

```
x = datetime.datetime.now()
y = x.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
df['date_appended'] = y

df_ora.to_sql('table_name', con, if_exists='append', index=False, dtype={'date_appended': sqlalchemy.DateTime()})

cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
'date_appended': '2020-12-01 08:18:36'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

[According to the documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.DateTime) the  `sqlalchemy.DateTime()` type produces `datetime.datetime` objects and this would suggest to me that you should provide those object when saving:

```
x = datetime.datetime.now()
df['date_appended'] = x

df_ora.to_sql('table_name', con, if_exists='append', index=False, dtype={'date_appended': sqlalchemy.DateTime()})
```

Note that this is an educated guess

Comment: That gives me this error:   ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string.     Seems Oracle wants the column type to be TIMESTAMP, not just DATE.    I find this curious........

Comment: @LandonStatis if you want to use `DATE` then you probably want the python type `datetime.date` and `sqlalchemy.Date()`

Comment: So, are you saying x = datetime.date.now()  ??

Comment: If you want the current date you should use `datetime.date.today()`